# Why can't load iptables rule with netfilter-persistent?

Tags: debian, iptables

```
man netfilter-persistent |grep start
       netfilter-persistent start
       start  Calls all plugins with the start argument, causing them to load their rules into netfilter.
       Plugins must implement the start flush and save arguments and must not rely on additional arguments for other functionality.
```

There is a rule in my `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`.

```
 cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4 |grep porn
-A INPUT -m string --string "porn" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
```

There rule has not been loaded yet,get nothing with `sudo iptables -L |grep porn`.
The netfilter-persistent service is activated.

```
sudo systemctl status netfilter-persistent |grep Active
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-09-07 11:39:12 HKT; 15min ago
```

Try to load it.

```
sudo systemctl start  netfilter-persistent
```

Check if the rule has been loaded.

```
sudo iptables -L|grep porn
```

Had not been loaded,try with `iptables-restore`.

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
sudo iptables -L|grep porn
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             STRING match  "porn" ALGO name bm TO 65535
```

Why `sudo systemctl start  netfilter-persistent` can't load rules into netfilter as the manual say?

```
ls /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d
15-ip4tables  25-ip6tables
```

`netfilter-persistent` service start automatically at startup.

```
sudo systemctl enable netfilter-persistent
```

None any pertinent logging output after starting the netfilter-persistent service.

Comment: Try a `systemctl restart netfilter-persistent`. From you output the service is active already and `systemd` won't do anything if the service is active already.

Comment: Maybe we  can call it a bug on debian os distritubtion,everytime i  reboot my pc,the netfilter-persistent is in activate status,but my iptables rules not loaded,"sudo systemctl restart netfilter-persistent" load it.

Answer (score 1):

`netfilter-persistent` is the framework for executing plugins to load netfilter rules. The plugin for iptables rules is called `iptables-persistent`. Do you have it installed?

You can check to see which plugins are being run by checking the contents of the plugins directory that `netfilter-persistent` uses, [`/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/iptables-persistent/blob/debian/netfilter-persistent#L14).

Comment: iptables-persistent is already the newest version (1.0.4+nmu2).

Comment: Do you have any pertinent logging  output after starting the netfilter-persistent service?

Comment: None,netfilter-persistent service started automatically at startup.

Comment: Can you add the full output of `sudo systemctl status netfilter-persistent` shortly after running `sudo systemctl start netfilter-persistent`?